# Choosing Specific Cells in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried multiple codes without luck. I have an excel sheet with 1800 rows and the following columns: ProgramCode, StudyBoard, FacultyID and ProgramType.
In the StudyBoard column there are some cells that are empty. I will then find all the empty cells in StudyBoard and their corresponding information from the other columns. Once I've found the desired cells, they must be overwritten in a new sheet.

I have the following codes, and couldn't continue, because even what I try isn't working.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim StudyBoardCol As Range
Dim PromgramCodeCol As Range
Dim rndCell As Range
Dim foundId As Variant
Dim msg As String
Dim FacultyIdCol As Range
Dim ProgramTypeLetter As Range


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SSBB")
Set StudyBoardCol = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
Set ProgramCodeCol = ws.Range("B2:B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
Set FacultyIdCol = ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
Set ProgramTypeLetter = ws.Range("D2:D" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)

For i = 2 To 1800
    Set rndCell = StudyBoardCol.Cells(Int(Rnd * StudyBoardCol.Cells.Count) + 1)
    FacultyIdCol = Application.Match(rndCell.Value, ProgramCodeCol, 0)
    ProgramTypeLetter = Application.Match(rndCell.Value, ProgramCodeCol, 0)
```

Comment: So you want to find all blank values in one column, and move that entire row to a new sheet?

Comment: Yes. finding all blank values in the column StudyBoard, and for each blank cells in StudyBoard I want their information from the columns: ProgramType, ProgramCode and FacultyID. And then Move the results to a new sheet. @DougCoats

Answer (score 0):

You could use SpecialCells to “isolate” blank ones

```
Dim cell As Range

Dim newSheet As Worksheet 
Set newSheet = Sheets.Add

With ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("SSBB") ‘reference “SSBB” sheet
    For Each cell in  .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) ‘ loop through referenced sheet column A blank cells from row 2 down to last not empty one
        cell.Resize(,3).Copy destination:=newSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) ‘ copy range next to current cell and paste to newSheet column A first empty cell
   Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use Autofilter (you probably want to add a test that cells are present to be copied before attempting to set rng

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TransferBlankStudyBoard()
    Dim rng As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SSBB").UsedRange 'Or limit to columns A:D
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
        rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Copy
        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Any feedback at all please?